# How to detect symbol ( # ) with javascript?

Tags: javascript, colors, news-ticker

i am making live news ticker. like twitter, if any hastagh ( #blabla ), that's be color red..

Anyone can help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: indexOf() may help you, please post more code

Comment: http://erictarn.com/post/1060722347/the-best-twitter-hashtag-regular-expression

Comment: /#\w+\b/g  if you search for hashtag in string, this regex should help... provide more details....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

> The indexOf() method returns the index within the calling String
>   object of the first occurrence of the specified value, starting the
>   search at fromIndex. Returns -1 if the value is not found.

Also as others have commented and if you are looking for a regex then this one will work for you as well

```
(^|\s)(#[a-z\d][\w-]*)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/pJ4wC5/5)

Comment: 'O' should be capital. indexOf()